# How do I parse this data with fabric?

Tags: python, fabric

I use fabric perform scrapyd task, the server returns the id of the task being performed, but I want to get this code below and put all id in list, but when I use **r.status** , there occur error: **'_AttributeString' object has no attribute 'status'** error, how do I get all id?the code blow:

```
@task
def stop_slave_machine(slave_ip = None):
    jobs_id = []
    with cd("/spider/distributed/wzws"):
        if not None:
            r = local("curl http://%s:%s/listjobs.json?project=WzwsSpider" % (slave_ip, scrapyd_port))              
            print(r.status)
```

and the server return data:

```html
{"status": "ok", "running": [{"start_time": "2016-03-28 18:21:21.951943", "id": "d10eae6cf4ce11e5a6646cae8b23c5da", "spider": "wzws"}, {"start_time": "2016-03-28 18:21:26.945244", "id": "d11a47f4f4ce11e5a6646cae8b23c5da", "spider": "wzws"}, {"start_time": "2016-03-28 18:21:31.941162", "id": "d12320ccf4ce11e5a6646cae8b23c5da", "spider": "wzws"}, {"start_time": "2016-03-28 18:21:36.941122", "id": "d12975b2f4ce11e5a6646cae8b23c5da", "spider": "wzws"}, {"start_time": "2016-03-28 18:21:41.941010", "id": "d131096cf4ce11e5a6646cae8b23c5da", "spider": "wzws"}], "finished": [], "pending": [], "node_name": "XXXXXXX"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a `JSON` body being returned. You can use python's [json](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) library to turn the response into a python object. From there you can iterate over the list of "running" to extract out the `id` for each.

Something like this:

```
from json import loads

# turn r into a python object as long as r is a string (hence loads not load)
returned = loads(r)

# Make a list ids from a list comprehension where we pull out the value
# id from each item in the list 'running' from the object returned
ids = [ r["id"] for r in returned["running"] ]
```

Comment: I need add a parameter r = local("curl http://%s:%s/listjobs.json?project=WzwsSpider" % (slave_ip, scrapyd_port), capture=True)

Comment: I don't follow. I've assumed `r` is already set in my suggestion. I can edit it to put your code inbetween the `import` line and the `loads` call if it would make it clearer.